# CSS Dropdown Menu Disappear in IE

Tags: css

My menu looks great in firefox and chrome. But IE. It dissapears. Anybody can help me ?

http://tinyurl.com/6yzd2jc

Comment: Internet Explorer prior to Version 7 doesn't support `:hover` on all elements except `<a>`. If you want to support IE<7, you need a JavaScript-workaround.

Comment: I have to give height because if I don`t background don`t come up. The problem is when you go over any menu item menu opens up when you go into the menu it dissapears

Comment: IE 8 and 7 I`m trying and it`s doing samething for both.

Comment: It would help if you would add the code you were having problems with directly to this SO page. That should be useful to others visiting this thread, now that your TinyURL link is broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my guess as to what's happening. Could be totally wrong.

The dropdown is supposed to disappear when the user mouses out of the link or the dropdown itself. But the problem is, there's a gap of a few pixels in between the link and the dropdown; this shows up in *all* browsers; I had trouble with it in Chrome before I even opened IE.

But when I *did* open it in IE, I saw that the links were even *further* away from the dropdown menus, so the problem was exacerbated.

If you go back to the CSS and make sure that there's no gap in between the link and the dropdown menu, does that fix the problem?

**Edit to actually *answer* the question**

There are a few CSS changes you could quickly make to fix the problem:

- Get rid of the `height` style on `#mNav`
- Add a `<div>` with the style `clear: both` to `#topNav`, *after* the `<ul>`
- Give each `ul li` a style of `height:25px`

It's not pretty, but I think that solves it.

Comment: Ubuntu + Chromium 12; I can't use the dropdown-menu either. Your answer seems probable.

Comment: I think exactly this is happening. If you hold the mouse down while moving to the sub menu, it stays open. Also when you move the mouse down very, very fast, it stays open.

Comment: +1 as this is definitely the issue. Though I think it might have been more helpful to have actually provided the css to solve the problem. **Edit:** @Sanooj that is not really a good solution as the dropdown would overlap and not line up with the bottom of the navigation.

Comment: #mNav {width:908px;height:29px;padding:0;background:url("mbg.png");}

I have to give height because if I don`t background don`t come up. The problem is when you go over any menu item menu opens up when you go into the menu it dissapears

Comment: @extelliqent That's why you add the `<div>` with `clear:both`, to get the background to show up again.